# can i modify the line in column in excel with macro or script?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to translate lines in columns in Excel with a script or macro method.

This is an example:

```
1 Eric
2 dupond
3 paris
4 24
5
6 Patrick
7 Thomson
8 lyon
9 28
```

It will be like this:

```
Nom    Prénom    Adresse    Age
Eric   dupond    paris      24
Patrick Thomson  lyon       28
```

You'll find attached a picture show what I need exactly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *Eric* in A1, put the following formula in an unused cell to the right.

```
=INDEX($A:$A, (COLUMN(A:A)-1)+(ROW(1:1)-1)*5+1)
```

Fill right three additional columns and down to catch all entries.

[image: another_transpose]

Comment: i want to aske  if i have in the 1st block 4 rows and in the second i have 10 rows and suppose i have a 3thd block with 7 rows what can i do in this case ?

Comment: Well, that is not the original question but in any event, you would be better off with a VBA solution.